# Memoizing exponential algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, memoization

There are certain patterns when it comes to identifying exponential run times. For example, if at each element in an array, the pointer can either make one, two, or three steps, we're looking at a O(3^N) array before memoization because there are three function calls per element.

However, I'm a little confused on what are the patterns behind identifying run times after memoization. Generally speaking, what's the relationship? I know what memoizing is doing--simply getting rid of repeated subcalls, but in an interview setting I don't want to have to sketch out a tree and scratch out all the repeated subcalls to intuit the runtime. Any ideas?

EDIT:

For example, the below problem brute force is O(3^N) and after memoization is O(n^3) and I'm not sure how to intuit this or if there's an underlying pattern I'm missing.

> A frog is crossing a river. The river is divided into x units and at
>   each unit there may or may not exist a stone. The frog can jump on a
>   stone, but it must not jump into the water.
>
> Given a list of stones' positions (in units) in sorted ascending
>   order, determine if the frog is able to cross the river by landing on
>   the last stone. Initially, the frog is on the first stone and assume
>   the first jump must be 1 unit.
>
> If the frog's last jump was k units, then its next jump must be either
>   k - 1, k, or k + 1 units. Note that the frog can only jump in the
>   forward direction

Approach #1 Brute Force [Time Limit Exceeded]

```
In the brute force approach, we make use of a recursive function canCrosscanCross which takes the given stone array, the current position and the current jumpsize as input arguments. We start with currentPosition=0 and jumpsize=0. Then for every function call, we start from the currentPosition and check if there lies a stone at (currentPostion + newjumpsize), where, the newjumpsize could be jumpsize, jumpsize+1 or jumpsize-1. In order to check whether a stone exists at the specified positions, we check the elements of the array in a linear manner. If a stone exists at any of these positions, we call the recursive function again with the same stone array, the currentPosition and the newjumpsize as the parameters. If we are able to reach the end of the stone array through any of these calls, we return true to indicate the possibility of reaching the end.

Java

public class Solution {
    public boolean canCross(int[] stones) {
        return can_Cross(stones, 0, 0);
    }
    public boolean can_Cross(int[] stones, int ind, int jumpsize) {
        for (int i = ind + 1; i < stones.length; i++) {
            int gap = stones[i] - stones[ind];
            if (gap >= jumpsize - 1 && gap <= jumpsize + 1) {
                if (can_Cross(stones, i, gap)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return ind == stones.length - 1;
    }
}
Complexity Analysis

Time complexity : O(3^n)

​​Recursion tree can grow upto 3^n
​
Space complexity : O(n). Recursion of depth n is used.
```

After memoizing:

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean canCross(int[] stones) {
        int[][] memo = new int[stones.length][stones.length];
        for (int[] row : memo) {
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        }
        return can_Cross(stones, 0, 0, memo) == 1;
    }
    public int can_Cross(int[] stones, int ind, int jumpsize, int[][] memo) {
        if (memo[ind][jumpsize] >= 0) {
            return memo[ind][jumpsize];
        }
        for (int i = ind + 1; i < stones.length; i++) {
            int gap = stones[i] - stones[ind];
            if (gap >= jumpsize - 1 && gap <= jumpsize + 1) {
                if (can_Cross(stones, i, gap, memo) == 1) {
                    memo[ind][gap] = 1;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        memo[ind][jumpsize] = (ind == stones.length - 1) ? 1 : 0;
        return memo[ind][jumpsize];
    }
}
```

Complexity Analysis

```
Time complexity : O(n^3)
​​Memorization will reduce time complexity to O(n^3).

Space complexity : O(n^2)
​​ memo matrix of size n^2 is used.
```

Answer (score 2):

So, it's helpful I think if you put a concrete example so I know exactly what you are talking about. But, I think I can guess. :)

From the point of asymptotic analysis, memoization "provably" helps if it means that you can put a much smaller bound on the number of subcalls that ultimately happen.

Classic example: Fibonacci numbers.

Suppose you have a naive implementation like this:

```
int fib(int n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
  }
}
```

Each time a call happens, two subcalls are made, and the parameter decreases only by a constant amount. So, you should be able to argue that the runtime is `2^{O(n)}`.

(More detail: When I call `fib(n)`, and at each branch pick one of the sub-branches until it bottoms out, there are at least `n/2` branches that occur. So that's at least `2^{n/2}`. Actually, "typically", meaning, if I picked one of the branches at random, `n` gets smaller by 1.5 on average. So there are more like `2^{2n/3}` subcalls. And, not more than `2^n`.)

What happens when you memoize it?

That means you create a buffer of length `n`, and cache the results of any subcalls there. `fib` needs to check the cache each time before doing the computation.

The point is, now instead of having `2^n` subcalls that do work, there are at most `n` subcalls that do work. The number of times we make a subcall that doesn't immediately pull the result from the cache is at most... the size of the cache.

It's similar with dynamic programming. When you allocate and then recursively compute values for your big old table, the running time is basically going to be, the size of the table.

So, in the fib case, you are supposed to get exponential improvement. Running time like `n` instead of `2^n`.

How to say that formally? Suppose I have (kind of fake) code like this:

```
std::vector<boost::optional<int>> cache;

int fib(int n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (cache[n]) {
    return *cache[n];
  } else {
    cache[n] = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
    return *cache[n];
  }
}
```

How long does `fib(n)` take to run?

First point: The third branch, where the value isn't yet cached, only can happen once for each value of `n`. (Because on any subsequent run, it would be cached.)

It follows: For any m < n, `fib(m)` is called at most twice, once from the `fib(n-2)` subcall (when `fib(m+2)` is being calculated), and once from the `fib(n-1)` subcall (when `fib(m+1)` is being calculated). Those two cases are the only cases that can directly invoke `fib(m)`, and they each only do it once.

So, the total number of calls to fib is `2 * n`. And the number of additions we perform is `n`, since we perform exactly one addition for each member of the cache we have to populate.

So the running time will be something like `n` times cost of an addition, plus `n` times cost of table lookup, as compared to `2^n` times cost of an addition.

I guess in an interview context, you'd think of addition and table lookup as being unit-cost operations. If you really want to have code that can compute `fib` for arbitrarily large integers, you can't use `int`, you'd need to use big integers, and the size will be about `log n` bits. Then, addition is like `O(log n)`, I think. So you'd end up with `n log n` asymptotically I think.

Comment: Upvoted-- but I added an example of time complexity analysis relationship that I was confused about. I'm familiar with fib example, but more curious about how that pattern applies to complexities like O(3^N) O(4^N) etc. Your point about how the time complexity is essentially the size of the cache is very enlightening though.

Comment: Hmm so, generalizing what I wrote, what I'd expect is that, if the branching factor is `b` and the size is `N`, the total number of recursive calls should be at most `b * N`. I mean, if you think of it as a graph where the points are the function calls, and the edges go to the subcalls, there are `N` points and the out-degree is `b`. If besides making subcalls, each node has to do `w` amount of work, then I'd want to say, over all time should be like `N * (b + w)` or something like this. (I'm assuming table lookup is O(1)) That's a bit hand waving but hopefully you see what I'm saying.